# Detect when a form has been closed c#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

I have a WinForm that I create that shows a prompt with a button. This is a custom WinForm view, as a message box dialog was not sufficient.

I have a background worker started and running. I also want to exit the while(`aBackgroundWorker.IsBusy`) loop if the button on myForm was clicked.

```
//MyProgram.cs

using(CustomForm myForm = new CustomForm())
{
    myForm.Show(theFormOwner);
    myForm.Refresh();

    while(aBackgroundWorker.IsBusy)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

Right now, in the `CustomForm` the `Button_clicked` event, I have

```
//CustomForm.cs

private void theButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Close();
}
```

Do I need to add more code to the CustomForm class, or the location where I declare and initialize the form in order to be able to detect a closure?

Comment: What form/class do you want to notify of the close of the window?

Comment: Writing this code makes no sense.  Presumably there's something *after* this while loop.  Move that code to the RunWorkerCompleted event handler for that BGW.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To detect when the form is actually closed, you need to hook the FormClosed event:

```
    this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form1_FormClosed);

    void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something
    }
```

Alternatively:

```
using(CustomForm myForm = new CustomForm())
{
    myForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(MyForm_FormClosed);
    ...
}

void MyForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Other reference that helped me a bit to understand : http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/185541-trigger-event-in-another-form/

`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(form2_FormClosed);
    form2.Show();
}

void form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Form 2 Closed!");
}
`

Answer (score 6):

You might be going overkill. To show a form like a dialog window and wait for it to exit before returning control back to the calling form, just use:

mySubForm.ShowDialog();

This will "block" the main form until the child is closed.

Comment: This keeps the UI light and simplifies the read and clarifying intention. No smells.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your background worker supports cancellation and as others have pointed out use the form closed event handler. This code should point you in the right direction:

```
using(CustomForm myForm = new CustomForm())
{
  myForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(ChildFormClosed);
  myForm.Show(theFormOwner);
  myForm.Refresh();


  while(aBackgroundWorker.IsBusy)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1);
    Application.DoEvents();
  }
}

void ChildFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    aBackgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle the [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event of the form to be notified when the form is closing, so you can perform any cleanup.

Comment: The form is a general form used throughout my application, so I can't say in CustomForm.cs OnFormClosing - clean up this specific part of MyProgram.cs

Comment: You might need to do it in all forms if the cleanup is specific to the form.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hook into the FormClosing and FormClosed events.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx

Closing is before it's closed.
Closed is after it's closed.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things...

First, it appears that loop is there in order to prevent execution form proceeding while the dialog is open.  If that is the case, change you `.Show(parent)` to `.ShowDialog(parent)`.  That will also take care of the rest of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `this.Hide();` is not the same as `this.Close();` in the actual dialog your overriding the closed event