# Form not null when closed

Tags: c#

I'm using form singleton that is created when needed:

```
    public PicForm dspForm;

    public PicForm getPicForm()
    {
        if (dspForm == null)
        {
            dspForm = new PicForm();
            dspForm.Visible = true;
        }
        dspForm.Show();
        return dspForm;
    }
```

When I close `dspForm` it not sets to null. Why? Since `dspForm` is not null how to know it is closed?

Comment: Why should it be set to null if you don't do so explicitly?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be `null` after closing it? There´s nothing in the docs that would explain this. Anyway when closing a form its `Dispose`-method is called which will dispose any unmanaged resources. Checking for `null` has nothing to do with disposing a ressource.

Comment: Is it invisible?  The Show() method does not return from form until the form exits.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Unless you set it explicitely to `null`, `dspForm` won´t be null. However it may be **disposed**, which is what you should care for instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when a form has been closed c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750602/detect-when-a-form-has-been-closed-c-sharp)

Comment: "how to know it is closed" Why do you want to know this? Your form is closed when someone hits the close-button (if existing) or the cross in the upper right.

Comment: dspForm.FormClosed += delegate { dspForm = null; };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PicForm` does not know anything about your variable here. You have to set variable to null (e.x. on FormClosed event).

```
    public PicForm getPicForm()
    {
        if (dspForm == null)
        {
            dspForm = new PicForm();
            dspForm.FormClosed += PicForm_FormClosed;
            dspForm.Visible = true;
        }
        dspForm.Show();
        return dspForm;
    }

    private void PicForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        PicForm picForm =(PicForm)sender;
        picForm.FormClosed += PicForm_FormClosed;
        dspForm = null;
    }
```

If you do not want to use additional events you could check if form was disposed (it will be if you close it ant it was shown with Show() method)

```
    public PicForm getPicForm()
    {
        if (dspForm == null || dspForm.Disposing || dspForm.IsDisposed)
        {
            dspForm = new PicForm();
            dspForm.Visible = true;
        }
        dspForm.Show();
        return dspForm;
    }
```

With this solution if you use `dspForm` somewhere else you also need to check if it was disposed. Otherwise you can get `ObjectDisposedException`

Answer (score 0):

When you close the form with `dspForm.Close()` the object is not set to null. If you want your object set to null, you have to do it explicitly:
`dspForm = null;`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
if (Application.OpenForms().OfType<dspForm>.Any()){//Your Code }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn´t assume any resource to be closed only because a reference to it is `null`. In fact having a null-reference and a disposed object don´t have **anything** to do which each other. You could even have two references to the same form. Would you expect both references to be null after closing the form? Why do you expect a reference to point to `null` after calling a method:

```
var m = new MyType();
m.DoSomething(); // why should this yield to m being null??
```

What you should be interested in instead is if your form is **disposed**, which will release any unmanaged ressources (such as file-handles for instance). That´s why `Form` implements the [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.idisposable)-interface. Calling `Close` on your form will automatically call `Dispose` which in turn will release those resources (unless you open the form via `ShowDialog`). Relying on form being null however doesn´t make it release those resources and thus results in memory-leacks.