# How to ensure Form is completely closed and removed from display before continuing?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried what I saw in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750602/detect-when-a-form-has-been-closed-c-sharp), which did not answer my question.  See my code and further explanation below.

```
// In MyForm : Form
private void SetupForImportantTask()
{
    // Does a ton of stuff to set up for ImportantTask, then...
    this.Close();
}

private void MyForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // otherForm is an instance of OtherForm : Form
    otherForm.ImportantTask(variousData);
}

// In OtherForm class...
public void ImportantTask(object variousData) {
    // Does a bunch of stuff that takes a long time
    // Provides UI feedback to notify the user a process in under way
}
```

**Explanation:** As you can see in the code, the idea is to do a bunch of setup for `ImportantTask` in `MyForm`, then call back into `OtherForm` with the setup information established *after* `MyForm` *has already closed*.

What I am seeing instead:

Even though I am not calling `ImportantTask` until the `Closed` event on `MyForm` has **already fired**, meaning semantically that the Form is already closed, `MyForm` remains open while the UI thread hangs, until `ImportantTask` is complete.  The UI notification of the long-running process is never displayed, and `MyForm` only closes after `ImportantTask` is complete.

If `MyForm` is not closed when the `Closed` event fires, how else can I determine that the Form is actually closed and cleared from the screen?

**Or:**

What silly thing have I missed?

Comment: Is `ImportantTask` running synchronously or asynchronously? Also, is it running on the main (UI) thread or a worker thread? If it's running synchronously and on the main thread, that behavior is pretty much expected.

Comment: You need to move all long running tasks into some form of Multitasking. Otherwise the UI thread is taxed out and nothing can be drawn - including the last change (closing the form)

Comment: Consider hiding the form **then** closing it.

Comment: You can run a Task in `ImportantTask` (the method already has the right name :). You can also change it in `otherForm.ImportantTask(variousData); this.Close();` (unless `this` is the starting Form, but it doesn't appear to be the case).

Comment: Many helpful notes here, thank you all.  With respect to the question as written, I take it that the answer is that it is an idiosyncrasy of the WinForms event and threading system that the `Closed` event does not wait until a Form is visibly closed (and cleared from the screen) before firing, and that there is no way to detect that a Form has been cleared from the screen; and therefore, the alternative is to use threading (or other) constructs in absence of such detection capability.

Comment: It's not *idiosyncrasy*. If `ImportantTask` is synchronous, you're blocking the UI thread. It will resume there when `ImportantTask` returns. If `ImportantTask` runs a Task (e.g. `Task.Run(async ()=> { await Task.Delay(4000); Console.WriteLine("Done"); });)` then it won't block and `MyForm` closes smoothly.

Comment: For what its worth, if you change `otherForm.ImportantTask(variousData);` to `otherForm.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => otherForm.ImportantTask()));` `MyForm` will finish closing before `ImportantTask` is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, a form will disappear from screen after Form_Closed event has fired, therefore after calling each method that has registered to that event. The `Dispose()` method is called right after firing the event ([from ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,835f7070c7e52263), check the end of this method).

If you want to make sure a form has disappeared, you have the `IsHandleCreated` property, which tells you if there is a handle associated with the form ([from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.ishandlecreated?view=netframework-4.8)).

About application design, a Form should be doing only what is has been designed for : display graphical elements and handling user input.

- User Input should be filtered and your form should be firing events that a controller class would catch and manage on another thread.
- When controller is done with user input, it should tell the form that it is OK to refresh the display.

Answer (score 1):

Your design as it is now is broken, if you call from a Form a method of another Form, until that method returns you are still inside the calling method of the first Form.

In other words, method A does not finish until method B ( called by method A ) returns the control flow to its caller.

There are various ways you can properly do this, you can simply hide your first form changing its visibility instead of closing it, or you can run the importanttask method on other form async, or you can even simply post a message to second form and terminate yoiur first form then second form will respond to that message.

of course, pay attention at objects life cycle as well and in the end the method you decide to use depends on the rest of the application and on your taste.

Comment: An asynchronous approach is likely the best.  The goal of this question, though, strictly speaking, is to understand a better way to detect that a Form has actually closed completely, including its UI representation, unless the answer is that this is completely impossible.

Comment: @Steverino With respect, I disagree with you. That's not your goal (at least it shouldn't be). You have a bigger problem than that. Having a long-running task that blocks the UI thread is wrong, period. That _is_ the main problem and one side effect of that problem is that the form doesn't close.